# Get User Session logged only to Joomla Backend

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla 2.5.27 and i need to create a php and get the session of logged in user in backend.

I have that code that i found on the webs

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($session);
```

so the problem that if the user is logged to frontend then it returns the user that is logged. But if it is logged only to backend this code returns guest user.

Can anyone explain me if it is possible to get backend session?
the php file with the code above is located in administrator path

Comment: Please try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) ;)

Comment: Sorry its already working. I cleared the cookies and everything works like a charm. thanks anyway, i will take a look at Joomla Stack Excange.

Comment: Please add this as an answer and accept it to mark it as solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by clearing cookies from browser and now it's working perfectly fine and always!